# how to get the previous page in apex?

Tags: apex, visualforce

This code gives you the current page:

`return ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().get('Referer');`

How do I get the previous page?

Comment: Are you trying to get something like previouspage.getID kind of (or) want to redirect the user back to the page he/she came from. If it is the 2nd case I would use window.history.back();http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_history.asp and use window.refresh() to show the changes updated on the page.

Comment: What are your trying to do? Return to the previous page? Think that Referer header is only sent by the browser when your actions is navigation, It is not sent when you press F5. Try document.referrer on javascript

Comment: If you are using standard controller, you can use `STANDARDCONTROLLERVAR.cancel().getUrl()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From e-bacho 2.0

If you are using standard controller, you can use STANDARDCONTROLLERVAR.cancel().getUrl() –

Answer (score 3):

The [HTTP Referer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer) header is the address of the webpage that linked to the Visualforce page being loaded.

If the code above gives you the current page then it is probable that you have posted back to the existing page.

Try checking the Referer when the page is first loaded and then persisting the value in a member until you need to do the redirect.

Comment: Another important note, HTTPS does not pass referer across domains in most browsers.  It is considered a cross site security issue.